# .Net Remoting, issue with firewall

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

I have a .NET remoting service listening on a Windows 2003 Server. As far as I know, the Windows Firewall is properly configured to let the information of the Remoting Application go out.

In my PC I have the other part of the communication, trying to execute methods that lives in the Remoting object. In theory, there are not firewalls that can interfere, but this exception is thrown:

```
SocketExcepcion (Error produced during the connection try, etc.)
```

I've captured traffic with Microsoft Network Monitor, and I've seen traffic going on between "server and client".

Ideas?. Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly does the SocketException say?

Comment: Hi Frank! (Socket Error 10060)

Connection timed out.

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or the established connection failed because the connected host has failed to respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Windows Remoting (the predecessor to WCF) is quite limiting as there are firewalling issues...basically, it will not work with a firewall, even though you have punched a hole in the firewall, the problem is the NAT'ting of the IP addresses, hence likely, you're getting a connection timed out socket error message. It might help you and re-assure that the problem may easily be remedied by allowing the traffic to be redirected, I have written an article on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/redirsrvr.aspx) which may help you. What you can do is put the application on the end point where the firewall is, put in the IP address that is facing publicly to the internet, and put the in the IP address that is to be redirected to the remoting server.

Feel free to contact me anytime if you so wish,
Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.